# Getting the length of multiple lists of list into a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have multiple lists of lists where I am trying to get the length but am struggling to find an efficient way.

I have used the code below to get the length of each list within the list.

```
genes1 <- sapply(unique_list1, function(x) length(x))

[1] 16560 16257 10995 14319 14434 16322 13004 16004 14224  5821  9030     0 10819     0 11203 11113

genes2 <- sapply(unique_list2, function(x) length(x))
[1] 10088  9453  2500  4066  5276  9083  5723  8262  6900  1036  3132     0  2739     0  4394  3020

combineddf <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(genes1), c(genes2)))
```

However, I have many objects up (genes1..genes1000) like this that I need to go through and was trying to figure out a more efficient way to make a dataframe.

Comment: you shorten your entire `sapply` call if you use `lengths()`

Comment: To clarify what @JilberUrbina is saying. The `lenghts()` function is equivalent to `sapply(data, length)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implied your data structure from your example. You could use the following:

example data:

```
set.seed(1)
unique_list1 <- list(rnorm(23),rnorm(23))
unique_list2 <- list(rnorm(23),rnorm(2))
unique_list3 <- list(rnorm(23),rnorm(14))
```

Code:

```
sapply(mget(ls(pattern="unique_list")), lengths)
```

output:

```
      unique_list1 unique_list2 unique_list3
[1,]           23           23           23
[2,]           23            2           14
```

Answer (score 2):

Or we can use `map` with `lengths`

```
 library(purrr)
 map(mget(ls(pattern="unique_list")), lengths)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1)
unique_list1 <- list(rnorm(23),rnorm(23))
unique_list2 <- list(rnorm(23),rnorm(2))
unique_list3 <- list(rnorm(23),rnorm(14))
```